# Compounded Dynamic Component Templates

Tags: web8.5, tbb, dynamic, razor

I built a setup in our previous Tridion 2011 installation which uses a Dynamic Component Presentation to render a container, and dynamic collection of dynamic article tiles in the following manner.

1. A dynamic Component: container, and collection of article Component Links (also dynamic)
2. Dynamic Component Template (Razor TBB): Renders the above Component's container and child Component Links using `@RenderComponentPresentation` with the below.
3. Dynamic Components: articles in above collection
4. Dynamic Component Template (Razor TBB): Article Tile

In 2011 this worked fine, it writes out a tile container, then each tile is rendered within in based on a Component Link and a type.

Having moved to Web 8.5 - I'm seeing something I don't understand. The first Razor DCP renders as it should, but instead of the tile HTML for the child articles in the collection - I get this:

```
<tridion:componentpresentation pageuri="tcm:x-y-z" componenturi="tcm:x-y" templateuri="tcm:x-y-z"></tridion:componentpresentation>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen or how to fix it if possible? I've done some reading about moving to REL and JSP as the Template Type but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is a change about the behaviour of the REL Component Presentation in Web 8, due to the change of the control of the target languages by the Publication Target and the new Topology Manager way of publishing.

To overcome this, there is a new property that can be controlled in the deployer, changing the `tcdl-conf.xml` as it is explained in the following link: [SDL Documentation](https://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3ED3EF09-4EE6-48B2-A618-D16634BB9DB8)

Basically you have to add a new property (if your language is .NET)

```
<Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="dotnet" />
```